# Amazon-ecs gem returns 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: ruby, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to use the amazon-ecs gem to access the Amazon Product Advertising API.

Right, now I'm running a very simple script to get it to run:

```
Amazon::Ecs.options = {
  :AWS_access_key_id => 'my_access_key_id',
  :AWS_secret_key => 'my_secret_key',
  :associate_tag => 'my_associate_tag'
}
res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search('ruby', :search_index => 'All')
```

However, this returns a 400 Bad Request error. Any Ideas on what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, here is how I resolved it:

First, I called `Amazon::Ecs.methods` and saw there were `debug`, and `debug=` methods, `Amazon::Ecs.debug` was set to `false` so naturally I set that to true `Amazon::Ecs.debug = true`, then tried the same search:

```
Amazon::Ecs.item_search('ruby')

# this time it gave the following output (secret keys masked by me)

irb(main):020:0> Amazon::Ecs.item_search('ruby')
Adding AWSAccessKeyId=*****************
Adding AssociateTag=*****************
Adding Keywords=ruby
Adding Operation=ItemSearch
Adding SearchIndex=Books
Adding Service=AWSECommerceService
Adding Timestamp=2015-11-13T20:25:04Z
Adding Version=2011-08-01
Request URL: http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=*****************&AssociateTag=*****************&Keywords=ruby&Operation=ItemSearch&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2015-11-13T20%3A25%3A04Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=****************************%3D
Amazon::RequestError: HTTP Response: 400 Bad Request
    from /Users/`whoami`/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/amazon-ecs-2.3.1/lib/amazon/ecs.rb:132:in `send_request'
    from /Users/`whoami`/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/amazon-ecs-2.3.1/lib/amazon/ecs.rb:101:in `item_search'
    from (irb):20
    from /Users/`whoami`/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Then, I copy/pasted the URL into a browser, which gave an XML response like this:

```
<ItemLookupErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-08-01/">
  <Error>
    <Code>AWS.InvalidAccount</Code>
    <Message>
        Your AccessKey Id is not registered for Product Advertising API. Please use the AccessKey Id obtained after registering at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/flex/advertising/api/sign-in.html
    </Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>********-****-****-****-************</RequestId>
</ItemLookupErrorResponse>
```

In my particular case though, it turns out, I had everything setup properly, however I had just recently created a new access key, and it seemed to take a few minutes to accept my new credentials. Funny enough, as soon as I realized that may be the case, and tried again, it worked!

**edit**: In case it isn't obvious, the answer is in the message:
"*Your AccessKey Id is not registered for Product Advertising API. Please use the AccessKey Id obtained after registering at* https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/flex/advertising/api/sign-in.html"